# What is MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener "code 703"?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, live-streaming

I am running a stream via `MediaPlayer`. When buffering starts, the code 701 is thrown. When buffering ends, the code 702 is thrown.

All codes are found on this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Callbacks).

However, `MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener` first throws the code 703, which I cannot find anywhere. Here is the code and debug output.

```
mPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i2) {
       Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener: " + i);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Logcat:

```
12-29 13:40:54.995: DEBUG/StreamingService(13811): MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener: 703
12-29 13:40:55.000: DEBUG/StreamingService(13811): MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener: 701
12-29 13:41:09.055: DEBUG/StreamingService(13811): MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener: 702
12-29 13:41:10.770: DEBUG/StreamingService(13811): MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener
```

What is the **code 703** thrown via `MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Code 703 ought to be `MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH` : "*Bandwidth in recent past*" ([source](https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/?p=platform/frameworks/av.git;a=blob;f=include/media/mediaplayer.h;h=1fad3833159dd95f1a0e7172929003dc37146da4;hb=jb_2.2_rb2_5.2#l111)).

This isn't really an error. It's a status code for information about what's going on in the media framework. Looking at the `AwesomePlayer` source code I see that it sends out `MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH` if the stream data cache is running low, which would eventually happen if you suddenly disable the internet connection. It'll then pause playback and start trying to buffer some more data, which is indicated by a `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START` message (code 701).

Comment: Thanks. I wonder where and how you found this :). But the major questions is now: What does "Bandwidth in recent past" mean? Do you have a clue?

Comment: "where": see the link in my answer. "how": I work with Android multimedia for a living, so I have a fairly good idea of where I should look.   As for what this info code means, my guess would be that the second argument contains the amount of bandwidth that has been used for streaming media in "the recent past" (whatever that may be).

Comment: Thanks again. Could the code 703 mean that the buffer is not 100% empty? I am asking as this is happening: I turn off Internet while stream plays, the sound stops trying to fill the buffer, **then it starts playing for less than 1s** (thou there isn't Internet connection at all), and then I receive error 702 and `onCompletion` is called.

Comment: These aren't really errors. They're codes for information about what's going on in the media framework. Looking at the AwesomePlayer source code I see that it sends out `MEDIA_INFO_NETWORK_BANDWIDTH` if the stream data cache is running low (which would eventually happen if you suddenly disable the internet connection). It'll then pause playback and start trying to buffer some more data (indicated by the `MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START` message [code 701]).

Comment: I have the same issue with streaming audio with mediaplayer. At some point (some minutes after starting playing) the playback stop. Play button doesnt work, i must pause (i get warning 702) and THEN play (warning 703 and 701). The stream play 1sec and then stop. I don't cleary understand what it means