# webview MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I am trying to load an HTML file in webview(e.g. mWebView.loadUrl("file://..player.html) which plays an html5 video, then displays an image for few seconds, then goes back to video and repeats this cycle in a nonstop loop. Every thing goes fine for the first few hundreds of the loop run, however after some random iterations the webview starts to act out, stops playing the video and displays these messages blew. Any clue what could be wrong?

The last status of the video before the pkaying stops is "durationchange" or "canplaythrough"

```
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
10-26 20:23:49.864  5168  5334 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (702, 0)
```

I already looked into [Android MediaPlayer : info/warning (703, 0),info/warning (702, 0),info/warning (701, 0),ProtocolException when try to seek from a random position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605675/android-mediaplayer-info-warning-703-0-info-warning-702-0-info-warning)

but did not help! its is so strange tha for the first few hundres times

Comment: Do you even actively deal with a MediaPlayer object?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well you say you have a WebView and load HTML5 Video into it. Then you get errors from the MediaPlayer Object. Do you have a reference to this Mediaplayer object?