# Android MediaPlayer info/warning (703, 0) info/warning (701, 0) slow wifi or data connection

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

```
03-25 05:52:15.329 8029-8042/com.mgh.radio W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (703, 0)
03-25 05:52:15.329 8029-8042/com.mgh.radio W/MediaPlayerNative: info/warning (701, 0)
03-25 05:52:22.547 8029-8029/com.mgh.radio D/PlayRadioActivity: android.media.MediaPlayer@4ca9cf
03-25 05:52:22.549 8029-8029/com.mgh.radio D/PlayRadioActivity: android.media.MediaPlayer@4ca9cf
```

I'm streaming radio from an audio datasource ip. This is my logcat, whenever my internet connection is slow radio stream get stopped.
I've seen [Android MediaPlayer : info/warning (703, 0),info/warning (702, 0),info/warning (701, 0),ProtocolException when try to seek from a random position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605675/android-mediaplayer-info-warning-703-0-info-warning-702-0-info-warning) , but it's about seekbar, but i don't have any problem regarding seekbar

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605675/android-mediaplayer-info-warning-703-0-info-warning-702-0-info-warning?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MediaPlayer : info/warning (703, 0),info/warning (702, 0),info/warning (701, 0),ProtocolException when try to seek from a random position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40605675/android-mediaplayer-info-warning-703-0-info-warning-702-0-info-warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case Music was getting stopped when display goes off though my "WAKELOCK" was on. I was be able to get around the problem by going under Android's advanced Wi-Fi settings and disabling the "Wi-Fi optimization" option, which claims to "minimize battery usage when Wi-Fi is on". For Mobile Data, it will occur if background Data is Turned off or data saver is turned on.

Comment: Yeah, but you can't expect your users to do this. So this isn't an answer to your issue, I would say.

Comment: yes, that's why i don't use MediaPlayer. i have shifted to Exoplayer